# Why does my Android Listview turn from transparent to opaque when I click it?

Tags: android, listview, click, transparency, element

Why does my Android Listview turn from transparent to opaque when I click it and how can I change that ? The Listview has a background and transparent elements and they scroll and work perfectly, except when I click it. When I click it the clicked element turns opaque and the background is no longer visible.

How can I change the behaviour so that the opacity does not change when I click elements ?

Edit: Could the focus highlight be responsible for this ? How can I disable that ?

Edit: Android 2.3.4, Tegra 2 device, Bitmaps created with Config.ARGB_8888 parameter.

Comment: set android:cacheColorHint=@android:color/transparent of the list view

Comment: I tried android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It was the focus as I suspected. It killed the transparency because the focus color is not transparent.

I removed that effect with:

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add android:cacheColorHint="#0000" to the list view in the xml

Comment: I tried android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" and it didn't work.