# Can't make ListView Background transparent in Android 2.2

Tags: android, listview, transparency

I'm having troubles with setting the background to be transparent on Android 2.2 (HTC Desire), even though it works perfectly in 4.0 (Samsung Galaxy SII).
I've tried both
**android:background="#00000000"** 
as well as **android:background="@android:color/transparent"** and tried to set it to the LinearLayout, the ListView and the RelativeLayout I have for each item in the list.

Is there some extra parameters to set to get background transparency with 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question necromancy (i was having the same issue and googling):
The answer may be in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198950/why-does-my-android-listview-turn-from-transparent-to-opaque-when-i-click-it), i.e. also set listSelector to make the focus color transparent.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>   android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Forgot to say that I also tried the cacheColorHint with both "@android:color/transparent" and "android:background="#00000000" but that didn't work either, still in 2.2 the bakground is always white :(

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your single items-views that are filling your list are not  trasparent.
I mean if you are having a list of white textViews, it doesn't matter if your list is transparent.

---

Create a transparent style-theme:

in your res/values folder create a styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

and then in your manifest add

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

in your list's activity properties

Comment: Nope, my single item views don't have any background color, and I also tried with each of them with transparent background but that didn't change anything.

Comment: If you have a listActivity and you want to see through the list to your previous activity you can create a transparent style and use it as a theme for your listActivity.

Comment: This is really weird, this solution didn't work either for the 2.2 :S I might just color the background of the listview the same as the background behind. It just really bugs me that something that should work doesn'n :P